# Ito isometry under characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In general for a stochastic integral of the form $\int_0^1 f(s) dB_s$ (when it makes sense) satisfies the Ito isometry: $E[(\int_0^1 f(s)dB_s )^2] = E[ \int_0^1 f^2(s)ds ].$ If $\Omega$ is our probability space, for a measurable set subset $A \subset \Omega,$ does it hold that $E[ ( \int_0^1 f(s)dB_s )^2 1_A ] = E[ \int_0^1 f^2(s)ds 1_A ]$?. I've checked several books but could not find a reference about this result, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $1_A^2 = 1_A$

Comment: @G.Chiusole how does that help?

Comment: You can prove Ito isometry first showing that it holds for simple/step functions. So I'd suggest you try checking your claim for such functions as well: what if $f$ takes just two values?

Comment: Pull the indicator function into the Ito integral, apply the regular Ito isometry and pull it out again

Comment: @G.Chiusole In general random variables cannot go inside the stochastic integral (in this case unless $A$ is measurable with respect to the initial filtration at time $t=0,$ so I'm not sure how it will help.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. How about this: Let $f$ be deterministic. If the formula is true for every measurable $A$, then it holds in particular for every $A$ in the filtration at time $0.5$. So then in particular the conditional expectation of $(\int_0^1 f(s) dB(s))^2$ at time $t = 0.5$ is constant. Which gives a contradiction for e.g. $f(s) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(s) = 1$ for all $s\in[0,1]$ and $A = \{|W_1| < \frac12\}$, then
$$
\Bbb E\left[\left(\int_0^1 f^2(s)\mathrm ds\right) 1_A\right] = \Bbb E[1_A] = \Bbb P(A)
$$
but
$$
\Bbb E\left[\left(\int_0^1 f(s)\mathrm dW_s\right)^2 1_A\right] = \Bbb E\left[W_1^2 \cdot 1_A\right] \leq \frac14\Bbb P(A).
$$